# PySpark - Create a Temp Tables for each unique item in loop

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I hope you will be able to help me.

I have one big table with information about resolved tasks by user. I need to create a random sample where size of sample is equal 10% of total items per user.
I already created a temporary table with information about size of sample (Table 1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dM97.jpg

And now I would like to:

1. Create a loop (based on Table 1) with a temp tables (created from general table) for each users with the appropriate number of tasks
2. Merge all temp tables into one master table with sample results.
3. Drop Temp Tables (additional)

[General overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hodx.jpg)

Is something like this possible to perform in PySpark?

Comment: Please provide a working example in terms of sample input dataset and expected output.

Comment: @AzharKhan  - please find what I would like to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI98y.jpg

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs,or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I already found a solution to create a dynamic table, but still I have a problem with size of sample:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
#df5 - column with Size of Sample
df5 = df5.withColumn("Size", df5["Size"].cast(IntegerType()))

dataCollect = df5.collect()
df5.show()
for row in dataCollect:
print(row['User'])
print(row['Size'])
#df2 - INPUT with all Records
df6 = df2.filter(df2.User == row['User'])
df6 = df6.limit(row['Sizes'])
df_Final = df_Final.union(df6).distinct()
```

And later I create a table with all selected samples.